# Open view Controller of Swift from Objective C class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

I have a view controller with objective c class , now i want to open the view controller that contain class swift. I have tried several times but it is not opening th swift class how can i open the swift class from objective c class.

Comment: you should use a bridging header. Please search to find more information about it.

Comment: i have bridging header i'm not getting now to call the swift class from objective c. @D.Greg

Comment: Are you using storyboard or XIB? This may help you http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-use-swift-classes-in-objective-c/

Comment: I'm using storyboard .@Nagarjun

Comment: Bro i have followed the link u have given but i'm getting the file not found error , I have also changed the header name as said in a tutorials. @Nagarjun

Comment: on some action try this 
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Your storyboard ID" sender:self];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I initially faced same trouble but after searching on web I got success. you should follow exact same as I have mentioned below:

Step by step Swift integration for Xcode Objc-based project:

Create new `*.swift` file (in Xcode) or add it by using Finder
Create an Objective-C bridging header when Xcode ask you about that
Implement your Swift class with `@objc` attribute:

```
import UIKit

@objc public class CustomView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
}
```

Open Build Settings and check those parameters:

- Defines Module : YES
- Product Module Name : myproject

> Make sure that your Product Module Name doesn't contain any special
>   characters

- Install Objective-C Compatibility Header : YES

> Once you've added *.swift file to the project this property will
>   appear in Build Settings

- Objective-C Generated Interface Header : myproject-Swift.h

> This header is auto-generated by Xcode

- Objective-C Bridging Header : $(SRCROOT)/myproject-Bridging-Header.h

Import Swift interface header in your *.m file

```
#import "myproject-Swift.h"
```

Don't pay attention to errors and warnings.
Clean and rebuild your Xcode project.
Done!

Comment: Bro i have done YES and Product module name also but when i write header file it shows me the bridge header file only. @Umang Loriya

Comment: It shows only this  #import "PK.House-Bridging-Header.h" in objective c class where i want to write header file.

Comment: Actually "PK.House-Bridging-Header.h" is for using Objective C files in Swift  but what you need to do is simply add this to .m file where you need to use swift object #import "PK.House-Swift.h".

Comment: Bro i'm really sorry but i'm not getting the point. I have done the above part u said to do YES and change the name also, after doing this now what to do ? @Umang Loriya

Comment: let's assume that you have objective c class files named viewController so in viewController.m file you need to add this line to access swift class files :#import "PK.House-Swift.h"

Comment: also don't forget to add @objc like "@objc class CustomVC: UIViewController"  as I have mentioned earlier and then you need to build the project before using that swift class in objective c code.

Comment: Bro it Is hsowing error that PK.House-Swift.h not found. @Umang Loriya

Comment: have you checked my previous comment? where i have mentioned about @objc and one success build is required before using #import "PK.House-Swift.h" also try in a separate project in which project name does not contain any special character as here you have "."